# Call JavaScript on an iFrame and trigger a popup -- Catch 22?

Tags: javascript, security, browser, popup, cross-domain

**Here's some background:**

- I am embedding an iFrame in a page
- The iFrame and the page are on separate domains
- I want to add a **button on the main page**, that when clicked calls **JavaScript on the iFrame**
- The JavaScript on the iFrame opens a popup (login) dialog

**Here's my problem:**

```
======================================================
|  Method      |  pop up |  call from page to iframe |
======================================================
|  direct call |    V    |            X              |
------------------------------------------------------
|  postMessage |    X    |            V              |
------------------------------------------------------
```

- Directly calling JavaScript on the iFrame opens the popup but doesn't work when the iFrame and the main page are on different domains.
- Using `postMessage` to trigger JavaScript on the iFrame works cross-domain, but now **the popup gets blocked**, since it's not a response to a direct user action.

**Any way around this?**

Comment: As you know, you can't interact directly with an iframe's contents, but you can change the iframe URL. Would it possible to update the URL and add a query parameter like "?popup=true". This would cause a iframe refresh though which might not be helpful?

Comment: Good Idea! I can do that. But will the popup blocker agree to open a popup on load? How can I change the URL of the iFrame?

Comment: I tried this approach, but the browser blocks pop ups that are triggered by the loading of the iframe :(

Comment: Can you not create a custom popup? As in a position absolute div that is hidden until you trigger it?

Comment: Unfortunately no. This is an OAuth authentication popup, so it has to run in a window with a visible URL line. In addition, a custom pop up in an iFrame would be limited to the area of the iFrame.

Answer (score 0):

I'll suggest to stick with postMessage, but implement a custom login popup. Using window.open is not a good idea.

Comment: Thanks, but I have to use a pop up dialog since this is an OAuth authentication and is has to run in its own window where the URL is visible.